# Php array count total value from key value pair

Tags: php, arrays

this is my array output:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "medium " => " 1"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    " small " => " 2"
  ]
]
```

My solution

```
$sumVariant = array();
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                                    //dd(trim($v));
                            $sumVariant += trim($v);
                        }
            }
dd($sumVariant);
```

How can I count total for both `medium` and `small` which return 3? Thanks!!

Comment: what did you tried so far ?

Comment: Look at the array functions in the PHP manual. It should be evident after a bit of research and thought. **Side note:** You should maybe think about changing your handle, you may not do so well as a **"d3bug3r"** if you can't figure this one out on your lonesome.

Comment: @Rasclatt thanks for advice.

Comment: Spoke too late! Looks like people are going to spoon-feed you the answer. It's your lucky day! : /

Comment: Do you just want to sum up all values of your array?

Answer (score 1):

I run your code as you write in your question. And have some modification like below. It gives you the correct answer.

```
<?php
$data =array(0=>array("medium "=>" 1"),1=>array(" small "=>" 2"));

$sumVariant=0;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                        //dd(trim($v));
                $sumVariant += trim($v);
            }
}
echo $sumVariant;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$total = 0;
foreach ($array as $inputArray) {
    if (array_key_exists ("medium", $array)) $total += $array["medium"] ;   
    if (array_key_exists ("small",  $array)) $total += $array["small"]  ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_walk_recurive`

```
$array_total = 0;
$arr = array(array('small'=>2), array('medium'=>1));
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($value, $key){
    global $array_total;
 $array_total += $value;
});
    echo $array_total; // output 3
```

Comment: I have tested and it's working fine. http://www.tehplayground.com/#dgD1FwNTs (hit ctrl+enter to see output)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $data =array(0=>array("medium "=>" 1"),1=>array(" small "=>" 2"));



 foreach ($data as $array_single) {
                           $sum_value += array_sum($array_single);

                }
echo $sum_value;
```

array_sum() return sum of integer represent as a string or int

examle::-

```
<?php
$a=array(' 5',15,25,'ajj');
echo array_sum($a);
?>
```

O/P ::- 45